# how to apply filters in inserting data to sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I have created an application to insert data to sq-lite .   i want if i enter same data again it should give e toast massage and then it only update that data not re-insert.
what should i do.....

now data is been re-inserted
method code of SQLiteOpenHelper.....

```
public void insertdata(String name,String ph,String area){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("phone", ph);
    cv.put("area", area);
    sd=this.getWritableDatabase();
    sd.insert("location", null, cv);
    sd.close();
```

method use in Activity class......

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                help=new MyHelper(getApplicationContext());
                help.getWritableDatabase();
                String myname=name.getText().toString();
                String call=phone.getText().toString();
                String myarea=area.getText().toString().trim();
                help.insertdata(myname, call, myarea);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("phone", ph);
    cv.put("area", area);

if (db == null) {
db = getWritableDatabase();
    }
if (isNameExists(name)) {  //check if name exits 
        id = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, name + " = ?",
                new String[] {name});
    } else {
        id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public boolean isNameExists(String name) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        String[] args = { "" + name };
        StringBuffer sbQuery = new StringBuffer("SELECT * from ").append(
                TABLE_NAME).append(" where name=?");
        cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sbQuery.toString(), args);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("AppoitnmentDBhelper", e.toString());
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: yes i've updated the answer.check that once..i've taken name as example u have to modify according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

The data is being reinserted because you're methods never check to see if it already exists in the databse. You need to add a query for some unique combination - probably name and phone number. If that query returns a result you can prompt the user to enter the data.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE name = " + name;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){ //if cursor has entry then don't reinsert 
    //prompt user with dialog
}  else {
    //insert data
}
```

Also you cannot use a `Toast` for this. What you want is a `Dialog`. If the data exists you can display a custom `Dialog` to the user that you could use to allow them to (1) enter new data (2) edit existing data (3) choose to reinsert the data they are posting. A `Toast` will just display a message to them like  - "reinserting data". It does not sound like that is the functionalty you want to achieve.

To update the database you can just use an update statment depending on what fields you want to change.

```
String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET";
if(!name.isEmpty(){
    query += " name = " + name;
}

if(!phone.isEmpty(){
    query += " phone = " + phone;
}

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE)
```

I put the if statments in to check for which fields are being changed and add them to the query accordingly. In the alternative you could use something like this

```
public int updateContact(Contact contact) { 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); 
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); 

    // updating row 
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", 
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) }); 
}
```

While I havnet modified it to fit your example you can see the basic approach. Hhere you can use conditionals to check if values are being supplied, if they are you add them to the ContentVlues list which will update them in the DB.

Comment: That depends what you want to do - are you trying to change the values or do you want to add multiple entries for the same person? For example - maybe you want 2 phone numbers - like home, cell, work. In that case you would want to insert. If you want to update then you'd use an update statment which I will add above